# Why the while loop is not pausing the coroutine?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to find a way to pause the game the whole game. timeScale = 0f is not working on coroutines.

I have this script that pause the game on escape key :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class BackToMainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool gamepaused = false;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            gamepaused = true;
            Time.timeScale = 0f;
        }
    }
}
```

And a script with a coroutine :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.PostProcessing;

public class DepthOfField : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEngine.GameObject player;
    public PostProcessingProfile postProcessingProfile;
    public bool dephOfFieldFinished = false;
    public LockSystem playerLockMode;

    private Animator playerAnimator;
    private float clipLength;
    private Coroutine depthOfFieldRoutineRef;

    void Start()
    {
        if (depthOfFieldRoutineRef != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(depthOfFieldRoutineRef);
        }

        playerAnimator = player.GetComponent<Animator>();

        AnimationClip[] clips = playerAnimator.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips;
        foreach (AnimationClip clip in clips)
        {
            clipLength = clip.length;
        }

        var depthOfField = postProcessingProfile.depthOfField.settings;
        depthOfField.focalLength = 300;
        StartCoroutine(changeValueOverTime(depthOfField.focalLength, 1, clipLength));
        postProcessingProfile.depthOfField.settings = depthOfField;
    }

    IEnumerator changeValueOverTime(float fromVal, float toVal, float duration)
    {
        while(BackToMainMenu.gamepaused)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        playerLockMode.PlayerLockState(true, true);

        float counter = 0f;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            var dof = postProcessingProfile.depthOfField.settings;

            if (Time.timeScale == 0)
                counter += Time.unscaledDeltaTime;
            else
                counter += Time.deltaTime;

            float val = Mathf.Lerp(fromVal, toVal, counter / duration);

            dof.focalLength = val;
            postProcessingProfile.depthOfField.settings = dof;

            yield return null;
        }

        playerAnimator.enabled = false;
        dephOfFieldFinished = true;
        depthOfFieldRoutineRef = null;
    }
}
```

But when I hit the escape key the freeze for a second or two but then the blurry effect in this script is keep on going then it also keep on running the game after this script part. It seems that the timeScale is not pausing the game at all but only for few seconds if at all. Or pausing only some stuff.

What I want is to pause the whole game. Maybe I should use a game state somehow? I don't want to disable/enable the gameobjects in the hierarchy.

I checked again now. For example the player I can't move it with the keys but I can rotate the player looking around with the mouse while in pause mode. But other things are paused like other npc's I have they stopped moving(Not using animation). So some stuff is paused but some stuff not.

Comment: You have code in your coroutine that says explicitly "do not pause this part when time scale is zero". If you want it to pause, why do you have this code here?

Comment: @DMGregory It seems to work now. I just left the line counter += Time.deltaTime; and removed the whole if timeScale == 0 part.

Comment: @DMGregory I see now that also the part of the loop while (BackToMainMenu.gamepaused) with the null return is not needed. I used it after google and saw it needed. Why others using this while loop ?

Comment: They're probably using it to do something different than what you are. It does not look to be appropriate for your use case, from the limited information I can see.